# Whenever I import Beautiful soup it infinitely asks to enter a number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Quite a simple problem I'm probably just doing something wrong but:
Even if I just put the import and nothing else like this:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

It automatically infinitely asks for this prompt:

Output:
`Enter a number:`

Edit:
I am running the same file.
[Entire program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNZD0.png)

Any suggestions?

Edit: I got a solution thanks to the comments, there was a  duplicate bs4 folder in the same folder as the file.

Comment: Are you running the same file that code is written?

Comment: Pycharm does not automatically modify the files to run when you select other files.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I am running the code written.

Comment: 1. Does it not happen when you remove that line? 2. Did you create a file named bs4.py somewhere?

Comment: If you click on the `run` button at the top of your IDE then that usually re-runs the last program.  Try `right-click` in the file and then `run 'spider'`.

Comment: can you show us the content of `BeautifulSoup.py` that you have inside the `bs4` folder? It this file created by you and without a `if __name__ == "__main__"` ?

Comment: When I remove that line the prompt disappears.

Comment: Please *do not post screenshots of code* (or output). Copy & paste the code and output itself, and post that.

Comment: right-click in the file and then run 'spider. However when I run it in command prompt it's fine? Anyone know why?

Comment: your problem most likely comes from the file BeautifulSoup.py inside the bs4 folder, where you have some code without the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition, so importing this file will execute that code. Please show us the content of this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a bs4 folder and the code might be imported from that folder instead of the original Beautiful Soup module.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is causing due to your background open files.
First make sure you had installed bs4 successfully on your device. If not then install by running  `"pip install beautifulsoup4"`
on your cmd.After that you close your all open files in Pycharm and reopen IDE.
Then try

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import requests
        url = " "#pass url
        req = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 
        "html.parser")
        print(soup.title)
```

Hope it will work